# LookupError: Model 'User.user' not registered

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-cms, cookiecutter-django

I get this error every time I try to run `manage.py makemigrations` `manage.py migrate` or `manage.py runserver`.

Full Traceback:

> https://pastebin.com/19G8Av5m

Short version:

> LookupError: Model 'User.user' not registered.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your app in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes.

Comment: I think you have in settings.py  AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User.user' right?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR Yes, do I need to change that?

Comment: Did you override django default user  in your django app?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I fixed the problem. I just needed to add the project name before `users.User`.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add my project's name before the model.

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'xxxprojectxxx.users.User'